# Embed a query and sub Query within a sql view (diff time in hours and min.)

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql

I want to display for the user how long ago this record was added. (Like "0 Days 5 Hours 6 Min.") so i need to take the total number of min. and make the math. I did it in c# but now I need to do it in sql syntax, is there a easy way to do that?

**UPDATE:**
Thanks to @Andomar answer here I got it to work as a separate query, Now I need to add it to a big view of the calls table..

```
 select case when days > 0 then CAST(Days as varchar(6)) +  ' Days ' else +  
        case when hours > 1 and hours < 24 then cast(hours as varchar(6)) + ' hours'
         when hours > 1 and hours < 24  then '1 hour'
         else '' 
    end + ' ' +
    case when minutes > 1 and minutes < 60 then cast(minutes as varchar(6)) + ' minutes'
         when minutes = 1 then '1 min.'
         else '' 
    end 
    end as TimeOpen
    From   (
    select  datediff(HH, dbo.Calls.CallDate, getdate()) as hours
    ,       datediff(MI, dbo.Calls.CallDate,getdate()) % 60 as minutes
    ,       datediff(D, dbo.Calls.CallDate, getdate()) as Days
    from    calls where Status <> 7 and Status <> 4
    ) as SubQuery
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the differences in hours like:

```
datediff(hour, startdate, enddate)
```

And the remainder of minutes:

```
datediff(minutes, startdate, enddate) % 60
```

Combined, it would look like:

```
select  cast(datediff(hour, startdate, enddate) as varchar(20)) + ' hours ' + 
        cast(datediff(minutes, startdate, enddate) % 60 as varchar(20) + ' min.'
```

To do conditional formatting, you could use a subquery:

```
select  case when hours > 1 then cast(hours as varchar(6)) + ' hours'
             when hours > 1 then '1 hour'
             else '' 
        end + ' ' +
        case when minutes > 1 then cast(minutes as varchar(6)) + ' minutes'
             when minutes = 1 then '1 minute'
             else '0 minutes'
        end
from    (
        select  datediff(hour, startdate, enddate) as hours
        ,       datediff(minutes, startdate, enddate) % 60 as minutes
        from    YourTable
        ) as SubQueryAlias
```

I'll leave adding days as an exercise for the reader ;)

Comment: that works but the days is not there, I have 2000 hours here.. it must not be more then 23.59 hour. I need a way to say if its more then 23 just leave out the day and display the day part.

Comment: @Ezi: You can check for a value with `case`, and use a subquery to prevent repeating `datediff` over and over.  As you can see, formatting is not one of SQL's strong points.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I made it work correctly, now I need to build it in a view.. I can't make it work.

Comment: You should probably calculate the difference in hours using the difference in minutes. Otherwise you might get weird results for ranges like `10:45 - 12:10`.

Answer (score 2):

Put your date calculations in a user defined function. Something like this.

```
create function GetDateDiffStr(@FromDate datetime, @ToDate datetime) returns varchar(50)
as
begin
  declare @Ret varchar(50)
  select @Ret = 
         cast(DayDiff.Value as varchar(10))+case DayDiff.Value when 1 then ' day ' else ' days ' end+
         cast(HourDiff.Value as varchar(10))+case HourDiff.Value when 1 then ' hour ' else ' hours ' end+
         cast(MinutDiff.Value as varchar(10))+case MinutDiff.Value when 1 then ' minute ' else ' minutes ' end
  from        (select datediff(mi, @FromDate, @ToDate)) as TotalMinutes(Value)
  cross apply (select TotalMinutes.Value / (24*60)) as DayDiff(Value)
  cross apply (select (TotalMinutes.Value - DayDiff.Value*24*60)/60) as HourDiff(Value)
  cross apply (select TotalMinutes.Value - DayDiff.Value*24*60 - HourDiff.Value*60) as MinutDiff(Value)
  return @Ret
end
```

And use the function in the field list in your view.

```
select dbo.GetDateDiffStr(YourDateColumn, getdate()) as DateDiffStr
from YourTable
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to specify what database system you are working on, but in sql server (and I assume many other database systems) you can [create a function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx) that has the same logic as what you have in your code and then you can call that in the sql query

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE VIEW your_view_name
AS
WITH
  ViewWithMinutes AS (
    SELECT
      TotalMinutes = DATEDIFF(mi, start_date_column, GETDATE()),
      other_columns
    FROM your_tables_and_joins
  ),
  ViewWithTimeParts AS (
    SELECT
      Minutes = TotalMinutes % 60,
      Hours   = TotalMinutes / 60 % 24,
      Days    = TotalMinutes / 60 / 24,
      the_other_columns
    FROM
  )
SELECT
  TimeOpen = CAST(Days    AS varchar) + CASE Days    WHEN 1 THEN ' day '    ELSE ' days '    END
           + CAST(Hours   AS varchar) + CASE Hours   WHEN 1 THEN ' hour '   ELSE ' hours '   END
           + CAST(Minutes AS varchar) + CASE Minutes WHEN 1 THEN ' minute ' ELSE ' minutes ' END
  the_other_columns
FROM ViewWithTimeParts
```